# Do I still have to pay for filtered-out results?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's assume I have a collection with 1000 documents. One of those has field set to true.

If I run a query on that collection similar to the following one, `db.collection("collectionName").whereEqualTo("thatField", true)`, would I still had to pay for the others 999?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only pay for the documents that are actually read by the client.  So if your result set it 1, then you get charged for 1 document read.

The exception to this is use of offsets, as described in the [billing documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing).

Comment: What about using `.addSnapshotListener` without filter, would I have to pay 1000x for every change on a document as in returns the whole collection on every document change?

Comment: The documentation I linked to is clear about listeners.